# Ajax call to servlet making additional call to servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a ajax call to servlet by jQuery:

```
function updateMapping() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/tool/updateMap",
            data : "mapArray=" + mapArrayVar+ "&submit=Update",
            datatype : "html",
            success : function(data) {
                $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                    location.reload(true);
                }); 
            }
        });

    }
```

this call is making no problem , but after updating while reloading the page its again calling servlet with "submit=Save" attribute.

```
<span> <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buttonabc" value="Save" />
```

so the data is getting save twice

Comment: Can you show the event handler that binds this function?

Comment: This is my update button
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button60" value="Update" onclick="updateZoneCircleMapping()" />

Comment: We need to see where the function is being called, if it's inside the form's submit event handler you need to prevent the default action of the event by calling `e.preventDefault()` or by returning false, also have you set the type attribute of your update button like `type="button"` if not it may be triggering the form to submit

Answer (score 0):

On the button pass the event:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button60" value="Update"
  onclick="updateZoneCircleMapping(event)" />
```

In the javascript prevent the default action:

```
function updateMapping(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevents form from submitting
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/tool/updateMap",
            data : "mapArray=" + mapArrayVar+ "&submit=Update",
            datatype : "html",
            success : function(data) {
                $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                    location.reload(true);
                }); 
            }
        });

}
```